# Is it possible for a wizard to learn a spell from a bard (or other classes) if it is on the wizards spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, spellcasting

I know it isn't possible to learn a spell through words alone, it has to come in a written form. So would it be possible for a Bard to create a spellscroll and then let the wizard learn it? Assuming the spellscroll is of a spell on the wizard spell list.

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111322/can-a-bard-teach-a-wizard-a-spell) although this assumes teaching directly.

I'm asking for RAW answers.

Comment: Is there anything that is not already answered in [What are the requirements for a wizard to successfully copy a spell from a scroll into their spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148256/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-wizard-to-successfully-copy-a-spell-from-a-scrol)

Comment: @Akixkisu I think the point of the question is: is there such a thing as a bard spell scroll? Would it still be "a wizard spell on a spell scroll", or would it be "a bard spell on a spell scroll". The other question and answers do not deal with this. (Maybe they should?)

Comment: @Szega you're right, but then again, there is no distinction between spell scrolls made by classes, only by spell lists per class, which is why i accepted the duplicate mark.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

A spell scroll is a spell scroll is a spell scroll. How it was created is irrelevant to how it is used.

Spell scroll rules are in the DMG and if it’s on your list you can use it (and for a wizard that means you can copy it into your spellbook).

Creating spell scrolls is an optional rule in both the DMG and XGtE but once created, it’s a spell scroll.

Answer (score 1):

The bard could create a spell scroll and the wizard could use that scroll to learn the spell.

From the DMG, p. 200 - 201:

> A wizard spell on a spell scroll can be copied just as spells in
>   spellbooks can be copied. When a spell is copied from a spell scroll,
>   the copier must succeed on an Intelligence (Arcana) check with a DC
>   equal to 10 + the spell's level. If the check succeeds, the spell is
>   successfully copied. Whether the check succeeds or fails, the spell
>   scroll is destroyed.